# Recursion and return statements in C

Tags: c, recursion, nested, return

Please explain how the return call from nested recursive function propagates all the way out to main?

I came across the following code segment in a book.  The printf output is '6, 12'

In the recursive function sumdig(), a return statement is called in **third** recursive call.

When sumdig() now returns to the second recursive call, sumdig() should evaluate to an
expression, not a return statement (i.e. return sumdig(n)).

But that is not what seems to happen.  The return call from the recursive function is being propagated all the way out to main.

Can anyone please explain how the return call from nested recursive function propagates all the way out to main?

The code below would have made sense to me if the recursive call was something like 'return sumdig(n)'.

```
main()
{

  int a, b;

  a = sumdig( 123 );
  b = sumdig( 123 );

  printf( "%d, %d\n", a, b);

}

sumdig(int n)
{
  static int s = 0;
  int d;

  if(n != 0)
  {
    d = n % 10;
    n = (n - d) / 10;
    s = s + d;

    sumdig(n);

  }
  else
    return(s);
}
```

Recursive calls for Sumdig

```
Initial call           :n = 123, s = 0
First recursive call   :n = 12,  s = 3
Second recursive call  :n = 1,   s = 5
Third recursive call   :n = 0,   s = 6   // Return statement happens here
```

Likewise 
For Second call...the static variable will increment by 6 again to become 12.

If my question is not clear, please help me improve it.

Comment: what does sumdig return ? an int ?

Comment: which complier are you using? Whether any warning during compilation? I am getting output like this 4199344, 4199344

Comment: Yes, i lifted the code from a book.  Sumdig is declared in Old style K&R format.  So return is an implicit int.

Comment: Using gcc on linux 64-bit. No warnings.

Answer (score 4):

The return value is undefined, because only the innermost recursive call returns with a defined value `s`. All previous calls for `sumdig()` are returning with an undefined value, because there is no return statement when the sumdig returns without fullfilling the  if` clause i.e when it returns from a recursive call.

So it might be, that `s` is propagated back, if the return value in the register stays unchanged, which may, or may not be the case.

To be safe, the recursive call should be:

```
return sumdig(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very old style C.  The return value from a function will be the result of the last evaluation in the function (in this case sumdig()).

Comment: noz, I was thinking along those lines.  So i put a the statement 'd = 99;' at the end of sumdig() function.  But output is still '6, 12'?

Comment: @kutichatan : try to run the program with the help of a debugger , you 'll get the complete trace .

Comment: Odd - perhaps the d=99 has been optimized out?

Comment: Just ran through the debugger, with dissassembly view in eclipse. The d=99 statement seems to be executed.

Comment: Looking at the compiled code the behavior is because the eax register (the return value) is just left from the call to sumdig.  The assignment of d to 99 happens without affecting the eax register - not sure if this is correct behavior or not (it probably isn't defined!).

Comment: If you use d=n+99 instead of d=99 you will get different values!

Comment: Even in old style C, the return value of a function was not the result of the last expression. If the end of a function is reached without encountering a return statement and you then try to use the return value of that function, the behavior is and always has been undefined. What is old style though is being allowed to not give return *types* to the functions.

Comment: @noz, The reason why EAX stays untouched, is simply, because there is no reason to modify it, as the function simply "falls off" without doing anything else. Of course, you can not rely on this behaviour, and on different architectures, some different epilogue might be used, which modifies the value randomly. Just put i.e. a `printf` after calling `sumdig` and the result will differ.

Answer (score 1):

Your question itself has the answer. static variable `s` updated each recursion when if condition false that time only function return to main. So last updated value of `s` return to main.

Comment: Not quite because s is only returned from the bottom level call (when n is 0)